# Why if one class forms a composition with another class, a different class can be asocciated with the composed class?

Tags: java, uml, associations, composition, class-diagram

Look at the following example:
[image]

The class named Fruits forms a composition with the class named Apple. That means that apples will be only instantiated when some fruit object is instantiated. Now my question is, if apples are only instantiated when fruits are instantiated how is it possible that a third class "Tasty Fruits" can access apple objects with an association relation if apple objects are inside fruits?

Wouldn't that association relation contradict the composition? I mean, in order to access apples, tasty fruits would need to access fruits as apples are inside fruits. I don't understand how and why this UML diagram is fine.

Comment: I don't see the problem?  Why shouldn't a `TastyFruits` object be able to reference an `Apple` that's part of `Fruits`?

Comment: Because what that uml diagram means is that Taisty Fruits objects have an atributte that is apples, but as the composition says that if apple is inside fruits, that means that no apple can be instantiated if no fruit is instantiated. So how can a Tasty Fruit have an apple atributte if apples are always instantiated inside fruits according to the composition ?  (Or this is what I have understood of composition )

Comment: One object can reference something that was created somewhere else.  So once a `Fruits` exists, a `TastyFruits` can reference its `Apple`s.  Sure, if there's no `Fruits`, there's no `Apple`, so in your diagram a `Fruits` would have to be created before a `TastyFruits`.

Comment: Additionally, a composition relationship means that `Fruits` objects have `Apple` objects as owned component parts, but it does not mean that those are the *only* `Apple` objects that exist.

Comment: 'Sure, if there's no Fruits, there's no Apple' but also ' but it does not mean that those are the only Apple objects that exist' . So an apple can be instantiated without the instance of a fruit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The composite aggregation means that `Apples` components of a `Fruit` composite have their lifecycle managed by the `Fruit` that owns them.

This does not prevent `Apples` to be associated directly with other classes. `Apples` could even exist without being owned by `Fruit` if the multiplicity on the fruit side would be `0..1`.

That being said, the diagram would be ok, with classes such as A, B, C. But  it is very confusing, with the classes chosen : in real life an `Apple` is a `Fruit`, and a `Fruit` instance (e.g. a given strawberry) is not composed of one or more apples. Similarly, a `Tasty Fruit` is also a `Fruit` and the association with `Apple` is as weird as a the composition.

In other words, the issue is not the UML rules, but the semantics usually associated with the chosen classes.

Comment: 'Apples could even exist without being owned by Fruit if the multiplicity on the fruit side would be 0..1' I can't imagen how is that possible. As far as I know as you said, 'Apples components of a Fruit composite have their lifecycle managed by the Fruit that owns them.' So how could an apple exist outside an apple ?

Comment: Also what composition says: A owns B and B has no meaning or purpose without A. So I don't understand why B objects can exist outside A objects according to that definition...

Comment: @Christophe, The composite class is not called `Fruit` but `Fruits`, indicating that this is a collection of fruits.

Comment: @sacacorchos, Your definition of composition is not correct. An _instance_ of A is a composition of some _instances_ of B. Other instances of B may exist without an A (if the multiplicity on the A side is 0..1).

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl yes I know and the same for `Apples` : I wanted to write in plural in view of the grammatical context and preferred to avoid overcomplicating the sentence for the purpose of keeping the singular ;-)

Comment: @sacacorchos to add on the admiraal's remark, a component can even survive its composite, for example if its ownership is transferred to another composite before the first one is deleted.

Comment: @Christophe what do you mean about:  if the multiplicity on the fruit side would be 0..1' ? do you mean like puting another arrow from apple to fruits?

Comment: An binary association is a statement about the instances of _two_ related classes. Therefore a multiplicity is necessary on both sides. You might have seen diagrams with only one multiplicity. This is probably because the modeler didn't want to show the multiplicities that have the default value, which is one. On the other hand, you cannot assume that a multiplicity is one, if none is shown, since multiplicities may be elided in the diagram, but defined in the model.

Comment: @sacacorchos as Axel explained, it would not be about adding a new arrow or association, but about showing 0..1 just next to the black diamond.